# csrf_field and _token error on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token

I started to learn Laravel. I have an issue with `csrf_field()` and `_token` error when I use  `theme001::create($request->all());` I get message like this:

> MassAssignmentException _token

Here are my codes:

**Controller: MainController.php**

```
public function post_social_media(Request $request){
    theme001::create($request->all());
    return 'Success!';
}
```

**Model: theme001.php**

```
protected $table = 'social_media';
protected $filltable = ['facebook'];
```

Route: web.php

```
Route::get('/social-media', 'MainController@get_social_media');
Route::post('/social-media', 'MainController@post_social_media');
```

Comment: `$filltable` should be `$fillable`

Comment: i'm really blind! Ty for help dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling you that you haven't allowed the `theme001` model to accept the `_token` property to be mass assigned. You can do so by adding `_token` to the `$fillable` property of your `theme001` model.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the guarded attribute and leave it as an empty array. You will not need to define which variables are allowed through, only the ones that are not allowed (if any).